# ARIMA forecast not working in python with error "too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to predict stock prices and I am getting this error.

```
import statsmodels.api as smapi
model = smapi.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train_data, order = (1,1,0))
fitted = model.fit()
print(test_data.shape)
fc,se,conf=fitted.forecast(638, alpha = 0.05)
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index = test_data.index)
lower_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 0], index = test_data.index)
upper_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 1], index = test_data.index)
```

for this line
`fc,se,conf=fitted.forecast(638, alpha = 0.05)`

the error I am getting is

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I am unsure as to what is causing the error. I have entered 638 because that's the shape of `test_data`

I really would appreciate the help in this regard!

*EDIT*

`train_data.head()` is like this with 1888 as the shape

[image]

and `test_data.head()` is like this with 638 as the shape

[image]

I hope this helps. I am still unsure as to why this is not working.

Comment: `fitted.forecast` doesn't return 3 values?

Comment: @BigBen No, it doesn't indeed. To OP: what are your trying to achieve here? And please, post a [mre]. We don't have your `train_data`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `forecast()` line of code you provided, there seems to be a mismatch between the variables you are asking for `(fc, se, and conf)` and what the `forecast()` function actually returns. The `forecast()` function in the `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults` module only returns the forecasted values for the specified time period, and not the `se` and `conf` variables.

I think you are confusing between `ARMA` model and `ARIMA` model. In `ARMA` model the `forecast()` method returns these 3 values.

To resolve your issue here, you can modify the code to only ask for the forecasted values. Here's the updated code:

```
# Only ask for the forecasted values
fc = fitted.forecast(638, alpha=0.05)
```

By making this change, you will receive a `Series` of future values (fc) for the specified time period, which is 638 days in your given example.

you can refer to the `ARIMA` documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html).

And, you can refer to the `ARMA` documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.11.1/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResults.forecast.html)

and here is a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as smapi

# ensure reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# time series for one year with daily frequency
time_index = pd.date_range(start='2013-07-01', periods=365, freq='D')
# random price values for training data
values = np.random.rand(365)*10
# create the dataframe
train_data = pd.DataFrame(values, index=time_index, columns=['Price'])

# time series for one month of test
time_index = pd.date_range(start='2014-07-01', periods=30, freq='D')
# random price values for test data
values = np.random.rand(30)*10
# create the dataframe
test_data = pd.DataFrame(values, index=time_index, columns=['Price'])


model = smapi.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train_data, order = (1,1,0))
fitted = model.fit()

fc=fitted.forecast(30)
test_data['forecasted'] = fc
test_data
```